# Unexpected Exception in Netbeans 12.6

Tags: java, netbeans-12

My java version 17.0.2; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.2+8-LTS-86. getting unexpected exception in NetBeans12.6 cannot invoke java.nio.file.path.startswith(java.nio.file.path) because path is null. Before Running the project itself am getting this error
Detailed Exception:

```
Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.startsWith(java.nio.file.Path)" because "path" is null
    at org.netbeans.modules.gradle.GradleModuleFileCache21$CachedArtifactVersion.<init>(GradleModuleFileCache21.java:143)
    at org.netbeans.modules.gradle.GradleModuleFileCache21.resolveCachedArtifactVersion(GradleModuleFileCache21.java:225)
    at org.netbeans.modules.gradle.api.GradleProjects.getJavadoc(GradleProjects.java:74)
    at org.netbeans.modules.gradle.java.queries.GradleSourceForRepository.findJavadoc(GradleSourceForRepository.java:83)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.queries.JavadocForBinaryQuery.findJavadoc(JavadocForBinaryQuery.java:62)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javadoc.search.JavadocRegistry.readRoots(JavadocRegistry.java:153)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javadoc.search.JavadocRegistry.getDocRoots(JavadocRegistry.java:106)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javadoc.search.IndexBuilder.refreshIndex(IndexBuilder.java:159)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javadoc.search.IndexBuilder.run(IndexBuilder.java:105)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're describing. Is Netbeans itself showing you this message or is this the output of running *your* code? If it's about your code, then maybe make sure that the path you use is not `null`? Also, [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: Before Running the project itself I am getting this notification I have added detailed Exception Please look that. I have not set any Path